# Can I embed fonts inside a document in Microsoft Word for Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, fonts

I want to save my Word doc so that all of the fonts are embedded.

This is so that it will look somewhat similar across when accessed on someone else's machine.

(I would prefer to use a PDF, but the people I'm supplying documents to wish to only use Word.)

I know that there's an option in Word for Windows to Embed TrueType Fonts (inside Tools > Options > Save).

But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in Word for Mac. (I've tried looking in Word > Preferences > Save.)

Is it possible to do this at all in Word for Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is it possible to do this (embed fonts) at all in Word for Mac?

No it is not possible.

> Support for font embedding within Office is limited to the Windows desktop versions of Word, PowerPoint and Publisher and is not supported on the Mac OS, iOS, Android or web versions of Word or PowerPoint.

Source [Document font embedding demystified](https://blogs.office.com/2015/07/06/document-font-embedding-demystified/)

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to achieve embedding fonts in a PDF file from within Word.

1. Select the print option (Command-P)
2. In the lower left corner is the option to "Save as Adobe PDF" (note, this is not the standard "PDF" option to be careful).
3. Select the output directory and Filename as usual.

I cannot tell if this option depends on some other system or Adobe software that may also exist on my computer, but it does seem to be the only option I could fine to force font embedding.

Comment: The question specifically states that a Word file is required and not a PDF.

Comment: Yes, good point.  I never even thought of embedding fonts in a Word doc so I apologize for the error.  However, the challenge of embedding them in an pdf was what brought me to this page and it is rather remarkable how hard this is.  My solution was the only one I could find.  And perhaps there are a few people out there with a similar challenge who will appreciate the solution.